# How to find trigonometric limit $ \lim_{x\to π} \frac{\sin x}{x^2 - π^2} $

Tags: trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

how to solve this problem? (without using l'Hopital rule)
$$ \lim_{x\to π} \frac{\sin x}{x^2 - π^2}  $$
I have no idea how to transform that so that I have no expression $\frac{0}{0}$
I suspect that calculating limit $\lim_{x\to π^{-}}$ or $\lim_{x\to π^+}$ does not works there.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Let $x=\pi+y$ and wonder about $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-\color{blue}{\sin y}}{\color{blue}{y}\color{red}{(2\pi+y)}}.$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rewrite as 
$$
\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\sin x}{x^2-\pi^2}=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\sin x-\sin \pi}{x-\pi}\times
\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1}{x+\pi}
$$
The first limit is (by definition) the derivative of $\sin $ at $x=\pi$. The second limit is easy to compute.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x^2-\pi^2}=\left(\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac1{x+\pi}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x-\pi}\right).$$